# How can you float: right and left in React Native?

Tags: react-native

how to put the amount label and value on left side

and

amount Paid label and value on right side

i am also want the button on front of Date on right side

```
<FlatList
                        data={this.state.data}
                        renderItem={({ item }) =>
                            <View style={style.listItems}>

                                <View>

                                    <Text>
                                        <Text style={style.textHeader}>Amount:  </Text>
                                        <Text style={style.text}> {item.Amount}  </Text>
                                        <Text style={style.textHeader}>Amount Paid:  </Text>
                                        <Text style={style.text}> {item.AmountPaid}  </Text>
                                    </Text>

                                </View>
                            </View>
                        }

                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    />
```

how can i fixed this issue

Comment: use flexbox https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the contents of the  `style` object, so that we can see what styling is already applied to your components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your existing styles, you would typically solve this by wrapping in a `View` like so:

```
<View>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <Text style={style.textHeader}>Amount:  </Text>
    <Text style={style.text}> {item.Amount}  </Text>
  </View>
  {...other rows}
</View>
```

*Note that I discarded the Text element that was wrapping your rows

*Note2: a common issue with `Text` elements inside a `View` with `flexDirection: row` is that if you have very long text in the first `Text`, it might push the other `Text` out of your `View`'s bounds. To fix this, apply `flexShrink: 1` to the first `Text` style (in your case, `textHeader`).